Install PWA on Edge on mobile not possible
When I open the site https://juke.nl/ on Edge on my desktop, I see in the url balk a button to install the PWA. But whenever I go to https://juke.nl/ on my mobile device (android & iOS), there is no possibility to install the PWA. Only to add a link to the home screen, but that just opens the site in the browser, instead of installing the PWA.
Does anyone have a work around for this issue?
Also when you type edge://apps in Edge on desktop, then you are navigated to the apps page, but that doesn't exist on mobile.

For Edge iOS, since iOS is blocking PWAs for any other browser except Safari, this is expected.
For Edge Android, in the latest version there's an issue that you can only add shortcuts instead of installing the PWA. I have tested in Edge Canary on Android device, and the PWA installation works as expected. I suggest reporting this issue to the Edge Dev Team by sending feedback in Edge Android.
